# Why is this CalendarView empty (showing nothing)?

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar, jodatime

I am developing an app called Infinite Calendar. And it is not infinite because everything has a limit and I am now finding this limit. I am using a `CalendarView` to display a calendar and JodaTime to help me to deal with dates.

My layout has only one view:

```
<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:showWeekNumber="false"
    android:shownWeekCount="5"
    android:id="@+id/calendar">
</CalendarView>
```

And I am setting the `maxDate` and `minDate` by code:

```
calendar.setMinDate (0);
calendar.setMaxDate (9223372017014400000L);
```

And why did I use `9223372017014400000L`? Because after some experiments, I found that is the maximum that JodaTime can get. And why didn't I set them in the layout file? Because I don't know the format. I tried a few times before but it kept throwing exceptions saying that the max is less than the min...

Now I think, that's so far so good. So I tried to set the date to some really big numbers:

```
Date date = new LocalDate (2000000, 1, 1).toDate ();
calendar.setDate (date.getTime ());
```

Actually I don't even know if I am doing this well or if I am just butchering this.

Now the strange thing happens. When I run the app, the `CalendarView` shows nothing but the month, the year and the days of week at the top! I searched and found another question similar to this:

[Android CalendarView not displaying the days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223984/android-calendarview-not-displaying-the-days)

But the answer told the OP to set the dimensions to `match_parent`, which I did apparently.

**So here comes the questions**, is there a special cause of this? If yes, what is it and how can I fix it? If no, what is the limit of `CalendarView`?

Update:

I tried to set the min date to default (not specifying that) and the max date to 1/1/2000000 and then set the date to 1/12000000. Now the calendar view shows the the date and other dates in 1999999! How weird!

Jon Skeet please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by Google's own Calendar app on my phone which only goes up to the year 2038, I imagine their `CalendarView` suffers from a similar issue created by the [Year 2038 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). This is probably the maximum date it supports, though I couldn't find any mention of that in the documentation.

You're probably better off looking into other solutions or writing your own, using 64 bit representations of the time - this should cover you for approximately 300 billion years...

---

An aside: JodaTime uses a 64 bit representation of the time, so all you have to do to get the max is convert 63 consecutive 1s to decimal which gets you `9223372036854775807`. No experiments required and slightly higher than your result.

Comment: See the update. I tried something else and the calendar shows dates in year 2000000

Comment: No, because I still don't understand why year 2000000 is ok but 292278993 does not

Comment: Oh right. You didn't mention that in your update. All you said was that it worked for year 2000000, and to be honest I'm impressed that it copes with that. I think you're going to have to accept that there are going to be limitations when using CalendarView. You should't expect it to work for the year 300 million.