# CalendarView not displaying current month screen

Tags: android, calendarview

I am using CalendarView in a dialog along with a time picker. the problem is when dialog is open CalendarView first screen is blank.  when i swap to next month, everything is OK.

[image]

my XML

```
<CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/m_10" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33544015/4862911

Comment: so shall i set it to max date ?? @AliGürelli

Comment: yes you should try it.